# Beta sites show > before site name

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Something just happened which caused the beta site names to be prefixed by a `>` sign. For example, on [Space Exploration](https://space.stackexchange.com):

> [image]

This does not appear to affect graduated sites.

Comment: Someone was 30 seconds quicker than you to report this :P

Comment: @Floern Indeed. And I even checked the front page before submitting the question!

Comment: So did I when [reporting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295220/209901)!