# Beta sites are diminished (their title has a leading ">")

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, beta-sites

I just noticed that Beta sites have a leading `>` symbol in their header:

```
<a href="https://spanish.stackexchange.com" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="top_nav.click({is_current:false, location:2, destination:8})">
                       &gt;       <----- THIS ONE!
                        Spanish Language
                            <span class="beta-title">beta</span>
                    </a>
```

[Spanish Language](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/):

> [image]

[Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/)

> [image]

I mean, I know their are not graduated yet, but they still deserve some love :)

Comment: Oh man it took me too long to post the question, duplicate by 3 minutes.